# jquery Change icon with toggle class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

### CSS

```
.plus { background-image : sample plus.png } /* ( + Icon ) */
.minus { background-image : sample minus.png } /* ( - Icon ) */
```

### HTML

```
<a href="#" class="button">

  <span class="plus"></span> /* ( + Icon ) */

</a>
```

### JQUERY

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.button' ,function() {

  jQuery(this).find('.plus').toggleClass('minus');

});
```

doesn't work properly, i need to change all - icons to + icon when click on the button, then change class + to - , just for closest button

Comment: You want to toggle 'class' for clicked `icon` or change all icons?

Comment: The class `minus` is not defined in you CSS. You made a typo. Therefore, your question is not useful for future viewers. You should delete it. You defined `inus` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.button' ,function() {

   jQuery(this).find('span').toggleClass('minus').toggleClass('plus');

});
```

Comment: I thought he want to toggle class for clicked button.

Comment: He had a typo in CSS. He wrote `inus` instead of `minus`, he just updated the question changing it.

Comment: But we can see the `.minus` class in the question

Comment: If you look at the edits, he changed it 1 minute ago!

Comment: May be I overlooked :). I think answer serves the need.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add `plus` class to all spans then trigger the clicked one only

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '.button' ,function() {
   jQuery('a.button > span').removeClass('minus').addClass('plus');
 jQuery(this).find('span').toggleClass('plus').toggleClass('minus');
});
```

```css
.plus { border: 1px solid blue } /* ( + Icon ) */
.minus {border: 1px solid red } /* ( - Icon ) */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="button">

  <span class="plus"></span> /* ( + Icon ) */

</a> 
<br/>
<a href="#" class="button">

  <span class="plus"></span> /* ( + Icon ) */

</a> 
<br/>
<a href="#" class="button">

  <span class="plus"></span> /* ( + Icon ) */

</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I'm not sure if it's what you are looking for.

```js
$('.button').on('click',function() { 
  var myClass = $(this).find('span').attr("class");
  if(myClass == "plus")
    $('.plus').removeClass().toggleClass('minus');
  else
    $(this).find('span').removeClass().toggleClass('plus');

});
```

```css
.plus { background-color : green; } /* ( + Icon ) */
.minus { background-color : red; } /* ( - Icon ) */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="button">
  <span class="plus">Img</span>
</a>
<a href="#" class="button">
  <span class="plus">Img</span>
</a>
<a href="#" class="button">
  <span class="plus">Img</span>
</a>
<a href="#" class="button">
  <span class="plus">Img</span>
</a>
```